# Asset management application (or distro)

Tags: software-recommendation

I am trying to find a good asset management solution (gpl) for our hospital (we should take care of furniture, medical machines and personal computers), of course working on Ubuntu and web-based.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a fixed asset management system:

Try [glpi](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/glpi) from the repositories or one of these sourceforge projects:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fams/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osinventory/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/starclient/

Comment: I had hoped to get a suggestion tested on the field but I'll happily test those and get back with feedback...
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

GLPI is available in the Ubuntu repository. It's a pretty well-made FOSS asset management system.

[screenshots](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?article42)

[demo](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?article47)

```
sudo apt-get install glpi
```

Answer (score 0):

GLPI and their Generic Object plugin is the way to go.
Just don't use the packaged glpi since its pretty outdated.

You just need a webserver , php and mysql/mariadb.

You can find the latest prerequsites here:
https://glpi-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prerequisites.html